# Error during conversion of .class file to jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am unable to understand the reason behind the error.I want to convert .class file to jar file,

on dos i write :

> java cf myjar.jar *.class

but here is what i get in return:

> Error: Could not find main class cf
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cf
>   ---and goes on,,,,

Why i am getting this error and what is it?

Comment: Use "jar cf myjar.jar *.class", not "java ...".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running the wrong command - `java` instead of `jar`. That's why it's treating `cf` as a *class* name.

You want:

```
jar cf myjar.jar *.class
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the jar command, java command is to running while the jar command will create the .jar file.

You also need to include a manifest file, which will determine the main class of your application. See [Working with Manifest Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). Without a manifest file you will need to specify the main class when running the app, like "java -cp JARFILE.jar package.MyMain"